# How to translate "黑科技" into English？

Tags: translation

As titled, how to translate "黑科技" in to english?

Is there any translation better than "fictional technology"?

Comment: Black technology, for example.

Comment: Surreal technology.

Comment: answer in iciba, with references to sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Black Technology"

It is a role of Japanese light novels *[Full Metal Panic!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Metal_Panic!#Full_Metal_Panic.21_The_Second_Raid)* .

> [黑科技（Black Technology）——是指倾听者所拥有，但是非人类自力研发；凌驾于人类现有的科技之上的知识。](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A9%9A%E7%88%86%E5%8D%B1%E6%A9%9F%E7%94%A8%E8%AA%9E%E5%88%97%E8%A1%A8#.E5.82.BE.E8.81.BD.E8.80.85.E8.88.87.E9.BB.91.E7.A7.91.E6.8A.80.E7.AF.87)

Black Technology is obtained from the Whispered who is another role of *Full Metal Panic!* . It is so knowledgeable that it overtops the existing technology of human being.

Nowadays, "黑科技" is often used to describe the companies which have unbelievable technology, [such as Sony](https://www.google.com/#q=sony+%E9%BB%91%E7%A7%91%E6%8A%80).

Answer (score 2):

"黑科技" comes from a comics. It means magical and amazing technical products that violated the nature of the world nor could be explained by the human knowledge. Inconceivable technology would be a good translation

Answer (score 1):

黑科技 is quite a parody way to describe technology that is beyond explanation so I think "**dark side of the force**" will be the appropriate way to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

I like 'black technology', but 'shadow technology' is also a possible useful alternative.